# MVC5 Upload File Request.Files works where controller method arguments do not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am uploading a file using a simple form. The issue I am having is the controller is given a view model as its only argument (The form is based on this view model). When I try to access the posted file through the view model argument it is `null`. However, when I access the file using `Request.Files["FormUpload.File"]` I am able to access the posted file.

I understand that in reality the form is attaching an id `FormUpload.File` which I can access. What I don't understand is how to use the view model to access the file instead. Are my controller arguments correct?

I've put the relevant bits of code below. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

The UploadView View Model:

```
public class UploadViewModel : ListViewModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewModel model)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase requestFile = Request.Files["FormUpload.File"];

    // Reference to View Model File
    // model.File = null

    // Reference to Request.Files
    // requestFile = true
}
```

View (Consider that FormUpload is an instance of an UploadView view model):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "RelevantController" , new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload a file.</legend>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormUpload.File, new { type = "file" })
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Cheers and thank you.

As an aside there are countless other questions that relate to "How do I upload this file. I keep getting null". My current workaround seems to be a popular answer.

Comment: What is the model in the view (i.e. `@model ??`)? - its is not `UploadViewModel` because if it was, your view would be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, ...)` You either need to use the same model in the POST method, or use the `[Bind(Prefix="..")]` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's a view model which has a `public UploadViewModel FormUpload { get; set; }` so I can access this view model.

Comment: Then change the POST method parameter to that view model, or use `[Bind(Prefix="FormUpload")]UploadViewModel model`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Brilliant, thank you. Could you post this up as an answer? I'll tick it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you view has `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormUpload.File, new { type = "file" })` means the model in the view is not `UploadViewModel`, but rather a model containing a property named `FormUpload` which is typeof `UploadViewModel`.

The reason it wont bind is because `UploadViewModel` does not contain a property named `FormUpload` which in turn contains a property named `File`.

You need to either

1. Change the parameter in the POST method to use the same model as
   declared in the view, for example, if its `@model MyModel` then the
   method needs to be `public ActionResult Upload(MyModel model)`, or
2. Use the `Prefix` property of the `BindAttribute` which effectively
   strips the prefix when binding - `public ActionResult Upload([Bind(Prefix="FormUpload")]UploadViewModel model)`